# Storing member variables as a reference, vs pointer

Tags: c++

I am working on some problems to better refine my working knowledge of pointers, references, and best practice usages. Here is a problem I am working through currently where I need some tweaks to my solution.

Problem statement:

> Make a Weapon class, that has a type string, and a getType that returns a const reference to this string. Also has a setType.
>
> Now, create two classes, HumanA and HumanB, that both have a weapon, a name, and an attack() function that displays something like: "NAME attacks with his WEAPON_TYPE"
>
> Make it so the following code produces attacks with "crude spiked club" THEN "some other type of club" in both test cases:
>
> ```
> int main(){
> {
>    Weapon club = Weapon("crude spiked club");
>    HumanA bob("Bob", club);
>    bob.attack();
>    club.setType("some other type of club");
>    bob.attack();
> }
> {
>    Weapon club = Weapon("crude spiked club");
>    HumanB jim("Jim");
>    jim.setWeapon(club);
>    jim.attack();
>    club.setType("some other type of club");
>    jim.attack();
> }
>
> }
> ```

And an important final question that this exercise is trying to get me to answer:

> In which case is it appropriate to store the Weapon as a pointer? As a reference? Why? Is it the best choice in light of what's asked?

I have "completed" the exercise, but I had to make a couple of slight modifications to the code block given in `main()`, in order to make it work -- which obviously isn't great. While mine does produce the expected output, I am unsure as to what I am needing to change to make the given `main()` work as is. I don't understand how you can change how you are storing the weapon without changing how it is passed in `main()`.

What I have so far:

main.cpp

```
int main(){
    {
        Weapon club = Weapon("crude spiked club");
        HumanA bob("Bob", club);
        bob.attack();
        club.setType("some other type of club");
        bob.attack();
    }

    {
        std::cout << "--------------------new section!!!-----------------------123" << "\n";
        Weapon club = Weapon("big, crude spiked club");
        HumanB jim("Jim");
        jim.setWeapon(club);
        std::cout << "Weapon set" << "\n";
        jim.attack();
        club.setType("some other type of club");
        jim.attack();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Weapon.h

```
class Weapon
{
    std::string type;

public:
    const std::string& getType();
    void setType(std::string t);
    Weapon();
    Weapon(std::string t);
};
```

Weapon.cpp

```
Weapon::Weapon() {
    type = "knucks";
}

Weapon::Weapon(std::string t)
{
    type = t;
}


const std::string& Weapon::getType()
{
    const std::string& type = this->type;
    return type;
}

void Weapon::setType(std::string t)
{
    this->type = t;
}
```

HumanA.h

```
class HumanA
{
    std::string name;
    Weapon* weapon;
public:
    void attack();
    HumanA() = default;
    HumanA(std::string n, Weapon& w);
};
```

HumanA.cpp

```
HumanA::HumanA(std::string n, Weapon& w)
{
    name = n;
    weapon = &w;
}

void HumanA::attack()
{
    std::cout << name << " attacks with his " << weapon->getType() << "\n";
}
```

HumanB.h

```
class HumanB
{
    std::string name;
    Weapon* weapon;

public:
    void attack();
    void setWeapon(Weapon w);
    HumanB();
    HumanB(std::string name);
};
```

HumanB.cpp

```
HumanB::HumanB(std::string n)
{
    name = n;
}


void HumanB::setWeapon(Weapon w) {
    weapon = &w;
    std::cout << "SETTING WEAPON!: " << weapon << "\n"; //I cannot get cout to print the value of the address that weapon points to
}

void HumanB::attack()
{
    std::cout << name << " attacks with his " << weapon << "\n"; //I cannot get cout to print the value of the address that weapon points to
}
```

Comment: Have you been taught about reference types?

Comment: Using your `HumanB::HumanB(std::string name, Weapon w)` will have undefined behaviour, you will need to change that definition. Did you omit some of the problem statement? as it stands `HumanA` and `HumanB` are approximately identical

Comment: @Caleth, no that is the entire statement. And yes I understand there are lvalue and rvalue types, but how to use them and WHEN, more importantly, is what I am trying to figure out here. It looks like for HumanA, the weapon will need to be stored as a reference since I am changing the type AFTER I initialize bob. Do I understand that correctly?

I tend to recall things a lot better when I put them into practice vs just reading a textbook.

Comment: A reference is a new name for an existing object. You can have e.g. `const std::string& Weapon::getType() { return type; }` and `HumanA(std::string name, Weapon& weapon) : name(name), weapon(&weapon) {}`

Comment: From the literal reading of the problem statement, you only need one constructor each for `HumanA` and `HumanB`, what you have now is two copies of a class that could be both.

Comment: You don't appear to have been given specifications for Human A & B classes, but need to infer them from the test cases. Note that in the first test case (HumanA) the Weapon member object is set by the constructor and that object is never traded for another (though the contents of the object is changed.) In case 2 (HumanB), the HumanB object is created without a Weapon initially and that is explicitly set later. Is it possible to implement that HumanA functionality with a reference member? With a pointer member? Same questions for HumanB. The answers are different for the two cases.

Comment: Yes, there is one. The purpose of this assignment is to learn about *references*. They're kinda like pointers, but you don't have to write `&` and `*` all over the place.

Comment: Reference members are often problematic. **You cannot change what a reference refers to**, and this makes assignment of instances of the class complicated or impossible depending on what you need to do.

Comment: @user4581301 I can't? That is what I did here for HumanA (bob), in this case, and it seemed to work, How is that the case?

Comment: *Is there a way to do this with the EXACT provided main.cpp?*  Yes.  Pass the Weapon by reference.  Have the HumanA and HumanB store the reference by pointer in a member variable.

Comment: `HumanA(bob)` would construct an all-new `HumanA` that is based on `bob`. If you wrote `fred = bob;`, and `HumanA` had reference members rather than pointer members you'd see the problem. The big point is you cannot repoint a reference, and that's a HUGE problem when bob wants to replace his longsword with the longsword+1 he just looted off the body of a dead rat.

Comment: @AviBerger So are you suggesting adding in another member variable (pointer or reference) to each Human class? or modifying the current Weapon member to be a pointer/reference?

Comment: No. I'm suggesting you pause and think through this. The Weapon member of HumanA/B might be object, reference, or pointer to an object. Making it an object is not compatible with the functionality implicit in the main that you are specified to use. (Why?) So that is out in both cases. The apparent purpose of this exercise to use the given main (and not a modified one, which seems to be against the rules of this specific exercise) is to make you think about pointer and reference members - how they work and what their characteristics are. What limitations does a reference member bring into play?

Comment: @AviBerger A reference member can never be changed. So in this case, since HumanB HAS to have it changed (being as it was never set initially), you can't have a reference member in the .h (Weapon& w). Which means the only other option here is to use a pointer, which I cannot for the life of me get to work. I have my code modified to where it will only cout the address of my pointer--and it gives me a compile error when I try to print the dereferenced pointer.

Comment: Good. You are exactly right about needing a pointer in HumanB. Now when you construct your HumanB without having a weapon yet, set the pointer to nullptr so that you can tell it doesn't have one yet. Next challenge is your setWeapon() member function. Passing a parameter can be by value(copy), pointer, or reference. Passing by value won't work here as then changing the original wouldn't impact the HumanB object. Passing by pointer requires a change to main() which violates your interface specification. So you are left with writing setWeapon to accept a reference and set a pointer from that.

Comment: As far as your printing issue. It seems that you already know how to do that, but may be letting frustration get in your way. One of the perils of programming. Go back and look at your HumanA implementation. You did it fine there where you also used a Weapon pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem statement is set up to get you to think about references and pointers and their different characteristics. It also explicitly describes some of the requirements, but provides you with a main function that you are not allowed to modify. This imposes additional implicit requirements so that you can learn to determine those and fit new code into existing code.

Since the `club` Weapon object's weapon type is changed after the HumanA object is initialized and that change needs to impact the operation of HumanA, either a reference or a pointer member is required to maintain a connection to the original object. An ordinary data member would not produce this behavior. The situation for HumanB is similar, but as the OP correctly concluded in the discussion in comments, "A reference member can never be changed. So in this case, since HumanB HAS to have it changed (being as it was never set initially), you can't have a reference member . . . Which means the only other option here is to use a pointer."

This same characteristic of references, as [user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301) points out, often makes the use of reference members problematic. It "makes assignment of instances of the class complicated or impossible". This is exactly because "You cannot change what a reference refers to". In the problem in the OP, this does not come up, but could become one should the code need to be expanded. It would also be an issue in other situations.

So class HumanA could use a reference or a pointer for its weapon member, though a pointer would probably be a better choice. HumanB must use a pointer.

When a pointer is used, but setting it to an object is deferred, it should be initialized to nullptr. Otherwise, it would be impossible to check it and determine if it was currently pointing to an object.

The remaining challenge of the OP's (seen in the comments) is to implement HumanB's setWeapon() method without modifying the provided main(). setWeapon() needs to accept a parameter to use to set HumanB's pointer member. Passing an object by value would create a copy and break the required link to the original object. This leaves passing a pointer or a reference to the object. Using a pointer would require a (prohibited) change to main(). So we have derived from the existing code the implicit interface specification that HumanB's setWeapon() take its argument by reference.